# Passing iterator of vector to the thread

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a trouble with passing begin() and end() iterators of vector to the thread.
I would like to understand the mechanism of threads and I trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

double accum(double *beg, double *end)
{
    return std::accumulate(beg,end,0);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    std::thread t1(accum,  &v.begin(), &v.end());
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that thread copy arguments and stores only rvalues - so here we should pass some wrapped pointer but how can I do this? Please explain me. I have already tried using & or std:: ref().

Comment: Do you know what `v.begin()` and `v.end()` return?  They do not return a `double`.

Comment: While iterators act like pointers (and are often implemented as pointers under the hood), they are not actually pointers to the underlying type; they are their own type.

Comment: Your problem may also be easier to reason with if you remove the `std::thread` entirely and see if you can call `accum` directly from `main()`.  You have titled this question as if it's an issue with a "thread", but I think it's a simpler issue with calling your function.

Comment: You may be confusing `begin()` and `end()` with `front()` and `back()`. `begin()` and `end()` return iterators, pointer-like objects. They do not return `double`s.

Comment: Make your code work without `std::thread` first. Understand why it should be that way. Then it will work with `std::thread`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `std::thread` and make your code work without it. It should be either:

```
using iter = std::vector::const_iterator;

double accum( iter beg, iter end)
{
    return std::accumulate(beg,end,0);
}

std::vector<double> v;
accum( v.begin(), v.end() );
```

Or if you insist to use `double *` instead for some reason:

```
double accum(double *beg, double *end)
{
    return std::accumulate(beg,end,0);
}

std::vector<double> v;
accum( v.data(), v.data() + v.size() );
```

Now you can replace direct call with `std::thread` in either case. Your problem is not with `std::thread`, you just are trying to pass wrong arguments to your function.

Answer (score 0):

The `::begin()` and `::end()` functions of any container in the standard library are iterators to the beginning and end of the containers data. These are pointer-like constructs used for accessing the containers elements. The standard libraries functions are design to take these iterators directly (see the bottom for links to std::accumulate documentation).

Declaring a wrapper function such that `std::thread` can call it it the right thinking as dealing with `std::accumulate` template parameters explicitly (or any algorithm for that matter) can difficult and tricky to get right however, a typical function is not the desirable method. Instead what you want is a lambda that encapsulate the call to `std::accumulate`.

Because you're using threads, I also used atomics so the accumulated result was thread safe on assignment.

Just remember to link with `-ltbb` and `-pthread`.

eg.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  // dummy data

    auto result {0};  // actual result
    std::atomic_ref<int> r { result };  // atomic reference to result

    // Captures atomic ref
    std::thread t1([&r](auto f, auto e, auto i) { r = std::accumulate(f, e, i); }
                   ,  v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    t1.join();

    std::cout << r << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

## Alternative

Alternatively you can use the parallel version of accumulate, `std::reduce` with the std::execution policies but you'll need C++17. Don't forget to link with the same libraries as above.

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

namespace stdx = std::execution;

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    auto r = std::reduce(stdx::par, v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    std::cout << r << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

## Links

- [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)
- [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref)
- [`std::execution` - Execution Policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)
- [Lambda's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)
- [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)
- [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)
- [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

  - [`std::vector::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)
  - [`std::vector::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)